# After Upgrading android 10 Q DialogFragment not working

Tags: android-dialogfragment, android-10.0

After upgrading Android 10 Q my dialogFragment not working, I have also converted android project into "AdroidX" but still the problem is same.

I am xamarin developer so please help me to understand this problem.

please check error:

```
2019-09-27 19:01:30.551 2177-2218/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-09-27 19:01:33.135 6797-6797/com.anotherroundapps.apps.kegid E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.anotherroundapps.apps.kegid, PID: 6797
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:5994)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7140)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7117)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27351)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:5989)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7140) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7117) 
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27351) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.anotherroundapps.apps.kegid.ManifestBuilder.EffectiveDateManagerFragment must be a public static class to be  properly recreated from instance state.
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:400)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.add(BackStackRecord.java:379)
        at androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:143)
        at com.anotherroundapps.apps.kegid.ManifestBuilder.showEffectiveDateDialog(ManifestBuilder.java:540)
        at com.anotherroundapps.apps.kegid.ManifestBuilder.itemClick(ManifestBuilder.java:275)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:5989) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7140) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7117) 
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27351) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
2019-09-27 19:01:33.147 2177-2201/? E/system_server: Invalid ID 0x00000000.
2019-09-27 19:01:33.193 1812-2126/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
2019-09-27 19:01:33.196 1812-2284/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
2019-09-27 19:01:35.611 2177-5427/? E/InputDispatcher: Window handle Window{bf1e32f u0 Application Error: com.anotherroundapps.apps.kegid} has no registered input channel
2019-09-27 19:01:35.669 2177-4730/? E/InputDispatcher: Window handle Window{bf1e32f u0 Application Error: com.anotherroundapps.apps.kegid} has no registered input channel
2019-09-27 19:01:35.738 2177-2285/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '94f2618 com.anotherroundapps.apps.kegid/com.anotherroundapps.apps.kegid.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2019-09-27 19:01:35.739 2177-2285/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'f095afe com.anotherroundapps.apps.kegid/com.anotherroundapps.apps.kegid.ManifestBuilder (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2019-09-27 19:01:37.342 2735-2735/? E/BeaconBle: Missing BluetoothAdapter
2019-09-27 19:01:37.393 2735-2735/? E/BeaconBle: Scan couldn't start for Places
2019-09-27 19:01:50.830 1935-1935/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2019-09-27 19:01:50.831 1935-1935/? E/netmgr: WifiForwarder unable to open QEMU pipe: Invalid argument
2019-09-27 19:02:50.865 1935-1935/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2019-09-27 19:02:50.865 1935-1935/? E/netmgr: WifiForwarder unable to open QEMU pipe: Invalid argument
2019-09-27 19:03:09.797 2177-2218/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-09-27 19:03:09.810 2177-2218/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-09-27 19:03:09.812 2177-2218/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-09-27 19:03:50.928 1935-1935/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2019-09-27 19:03:50.929 1935-1935/? E/netmgr: WifiForwarder unable to open QEMU pipe: Invalid argument
2019-09-27 19:03:56.639 2735-6578/? E/WakeLock: GCM_HB_ALARM release without a matched acquire!
2019-09-27 19:03:56.645 2735-6578/? E/WakeLock: GCM_CONN_ALARM release without a matched acquire!
2019-09-27 19:03:56.893 2177-2218/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-09-27 19:03:56.897 2177-2218/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2019-09-27 19:04:02.386 2735-6917/? E/WakeLock: GCM_CONN_ALARM release without a matched acquire!
2019-09-27 19:04:45.446 2177-2218/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
```

1. I have tried with AndroidX and some of the googles artical but couldn't get much of help

   public void showEffectiveDateDialog() {
           DialogFragment newFragment = new EffectiveDateManagerFragment();
           newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
       }

   ```
   public class EffectiveDateManagerFragment extends DialogFragment {
       @Override
       public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

           DateTime currentEffectiveDate = mNewManifest.getEffectiveDate();

           // prompt use scan date or select another date
           ArrayList<CharSequence> selections = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();

           if (currentEffectiveDate != null)
               selections.add(Html.fromHtml(String.format("Current selection: <b>%s</b>", currentEffectiveDate.toString(KegIdApplication.DATETIME_DISPLAY_FORMAT))));
           else
               selections.add(Html.fromHtml(String.format("Current selection: <b>%s</b>", getString(R.string.label_use_scan_date))));

           selections.add(getString(R.string.label_use_scan_date));
           selections.add(getString(R.string.label_choose_a_date));

           AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
           builder.setTitle(R.string.label_effectivedate).setItems(selections.toArray(new CharSequence[selections.size()]), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   switch (which) {
                       case 0:
                           //leave as is
                           dialog.dismiss();
                           break;
                       case 1:
                           // use scan date, clear effective date
                           mNewManifest.setEffectiveDate(null);
                           mEffectiveDateText.setText(R.string.label_use_scan_date);
                           break;
                       case 2:
                           // choose an effectivedate
                           dialog.dismiss();
                           DialogFragment newFragment = new DateTimePickerFragment(mNewManifest.getEffectiveDate());
                           newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
                           break;
                       default:
                           //cancel;
                           dialog.dismiss();
                           break;
                   }
               }
           });

           //builder.setMessage("Choose the effective date for these kegs");
           return builder.create();

       }
   }
   ```

I have custom dialog will have to open

Comment: `Fragment com.anotherroundapps.apps.kegid.ManifestBuilder.EffectiveDateManagerFragment must be a public static class to be  properly recreated from instance state.` -- is your `EffectiveDateManagerFragment` in an `EffectiveDateManagerFragment.java` file? If not, move it there, making it a regular Java class.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is I have created new java class for EffectiveDateManagerFragment and other related class changes into static class it solved my problem